# Django model serializer

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I am using `django-rest-framework` - I want to rename (in list) the field in model serializer and to update with same name which I renamed in list (to update).

```
class ConfiglistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Config
        fields = ('id', 'configname', 'mac_address')
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return {
            'id': obj.id,
            'configname': obj.name,
            'macAddress': obj.mac_address
        }
```

How to update with the name `("configname" , "macAddress")` in `put` or `patch`?

Comment: Here's how - http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do anything on update. Just define fields with names , that you want by using the `serializer fields` and specifying source param. The rest-framwork serilizer will do other parts.

For ex.  `macAddress = serializers.CharField(source='mac_address')`

See here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/ to how serializer fields works

Comment: @Ramesh  What is your expectation ?. Tell exactly.

Comment: thanks exactly i need this ...thanks nanbaaaaa @Rajez

Comment: Okay.Could you make voteup. If the answer is correct , then  why it is voted down..!!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use parser and renderer for camel case:

```
$ pip install djangorestframework-camel-case
```

And to add the render and parser to your django settings file.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.render.CamelCaseJSONRenderer',
        # Any other renders
    ),

    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseJSONParser',
        # Any other parsers
    ),
}
```

That way you will be able to work with snake_case in your serializer, and camelCase in API without custom `to_representation` method